# Why am I getting "remote: fatal: path not found: HEAD" error when I run git archive?

Tags: git

I am trying to extract a single file from my git repo like so ...

```
$ git archive --remote=red-git:/opt/red-git/RED-puppet.git development HEAD:usr/local/scripts/apply.sh | tar -xvf -
```

... but it doesn't work. I get this error message.

```
remote: fatal: path not found: HEAD:usr/local/scripts/apply.sh
remote: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
fatal: sent error to the client: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I know there are a ton of questions and answer about how to extract a single file from git,
but none of them have been able to explain to me why am I getting the error:

```
remote: fatal: path not found: HEAD:usr/local/scripts/apply.sh
```

I know the shell script is there because I can do this ...

```
$ git archive --remote=red-git:/opt/red-git/RED-puppet.git development | tar -xvf - | grep apply.sh
...
usr/local/scripts/apply.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my `HEAD` against the wall and much trail and error I came upon this command-line that does the trick:

```
git archive --remote=red-git:/opt/red-git/RED-puppet.git development usr/local/scripts/apply.sh | tar -xvf -
```

No `HEAD:`.  Good I wasn't really sure what that meant anyways. :)